# C# Pig Latin with Regex Replace

Tags: c#, regex, string

First off- This is a Homework problem. Just getting that out there. Trying to build a Pig Latin Translator in C#, we have to use Regex replace but I'm having some issues. Not allowed to use the Split method to obtain an array of words.  We have to use the static method **Replace** of type **Regex**. White Space, punctuation linebreaks et should be preserved. Capitalized words should remain so. For those unfamiliar with the rules of Pig Latin-

1. If the string begins with a vowel, add "way" to the string.  (vowels are a,e,i,o,u)
   Examples:  Pig-Latin for "orange" is "orangeway", Pig-Latin for “eating” is “eatingway”
2. Otherwise, find the first occurrence of a vowel, move all the characters before the vowel to the end of the word, and add "ay".
   (in the middle of the word ‘y’ also counts as a vowel, but NOT at the beginning)
   Examples:  Pig-Latin for "story" is "orystay" since the characters "st" occur before the first vowel; Pig-Latin for "crystal" is "ystalcray", but Pig-Latin for "yellow" is "ellowyay".
3. If there are no vowels, add "ay".Examples:  Pig-Latin for "mph" is "mphay", Pig-Latin for RPM is RPMay

I've got a ton of commented out code, so I'll remove that for reading ease. 
My test sentence is **"Eat monkey poo."** I'm getting **"Ewayaayt moaynkeayy poayoay."**
I know Regex is 'greedy', but I can't figure out how to get it to stop with just the first vowel it finds. Using Textboxes as well.

```
namespace AssignmentPigLatin
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OriginalTb.Text = "Eat monkey poo.";
        }

        private void translateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string vowels = "[AEIOUaeiou]";
            var regex = new Regex(vowels);
            var translation = regex.Replace(OriginalTb.Text, TranslateToPigLatin);
            PigLatinTb.Text = translation;
        }

        private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OriginalTb.Text = "";
            PigLatinTb.Text = "";
        }

        static string TranslateToPigLatin(Match match)
        {

            string word = match.ToString();
            string firstLetters = word.Substring(0, match.Length);
            string restLetters = word.Substring(firstLetters.Length - 1, word.Length-1);
            string newWord;
            if (match.Index == 0)
            {

                return word + "way"; 

            }
            else
            {
                return restLetters + firstLetters + "ay";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: good one. I am done. Will post the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was interesting to answer. Don't forget to attribute me ;)

Add this method in your class `AssignmentPigLatin`

```
private string PigLatinTranslator(string s)
    {
        s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\b[a|e|i|o|u]\w+)", "$1way", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        List<string> words = new List<string>();
        foreach (Match v in Regex.Matches(s, @"\w+"))
        {
            string result;
            if (!v.Value.EndsWith("way"))
            {
                result = Regex.Replace(v.Value, @"([^a|e|i|o|u]*)([a|e|i|o|u])(\w+)", "$2$3$1ay", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                words.Add(result);
            }
            else { words.Add(v.Value); }
        }
        s = string.Join(" ", words);
        words.Clear();
        foreach (Match v in Regex.Matches(s,@"\w+"))
        {
            string result = Regex.Replace(v.Value, @"\b([^a|e|i|o|u]+)\b", "$1ay", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            words.Add(result);
        }
        s = string.Join(" ", words);
        return s;
    }
```

Call it like this:

```
string test = "MPH Eat monkey poo."; // Added MPH, so that you can test my method works or not.
string result = PigLatinTranslator(test);
Console.WriteLine(result); // MPHay Eatway onkeymay oopay.
```

Comment: @PrestonGuillot, yeah. Now no Spilt method :)

Comment: This works for the words, but it's removing and ignoring spacing and punctuation. Trying to figure out how to fix that.

Comment: It is not removing spaces and punctuations. the spaces are intact and `.` was untouched

Answer (score 1):

Easier and more clear solution is to use `Regex.Replace` with lambda.

```
static string TranslateToPigLatin(string input)
{
    char[] vowels = new[] { 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    char[] vowelsExtended = vowels.Concat(new[] { 'Y', 'y' }).ToArray();
    string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\w+", m =>
        {
            string word = m.Value;
            if (vowels.Contains(word[0]))
                return word + "way";
            else
            {
                int indexOfVowel = word.IndexOfAny(vowelsExtended, 1);
                if (indexOfVowel == -1)
                    return word + "ay";
                else
                    return word.Substring(indexOfVowel) + word.Substring(0, indexOfVowel) + "ay";
            }
        });
    return output;
}
```